# testing randomness in a grid

Tags: randomness

I need help with figuring out what kind of statistics I need to run to test for randomness in a grid for small mammal trapping.

The grid consists on 64 traps, arranged in 8 rows of 8. The image attached shows an example of the grid and the red Xs indicate captures. There appears to be a pattern of trapping on the exterior of the grid, but I need to run a statistical analysis to see if it is random or not. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "random" here, equal probability of trapping in all cells? Is it really all that possible for an animal to be trapped in the interior cells (they'd have to make it past all the others first)?

Comment: There's no real need for any analysis to determine whether this pattern is random: it isn't even remotely so.  Of greater concern is that this hypothesis (of greater intensity on the border) may be a *post hoc* hypothesis derived from examination of the pattern.  If so, it isn't testable using these data: you need independent data.